# How to get full stack trace from Tkinter Tk.report_callback_exception?

Tags: python, exception, tkinter, traceback

Whenever I get an error in my Tkinter application, I would like to get a full stack trace of where the error occurred, through all of the functions the program is currently in.

Before my root window opens, I have `Tk.report_callback_exception = TKINTERERROR` and I am able to get the traceback object of the error in `TKINTERERROR()`. However, when I attempt to print the traceback (with `traceback.format_list(traceback.extract_tb(tracebackObject)))`, it only gives me the most recent function call, and the line the error occurred on. Is this all that is possible with Tkinter exceptions, or is there a way to get the entire stack trace?

To elaborate, what I expect to get is something like this, in which all the functions the program is currently in are given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfilepath", line 13, in <module>
    func1()
  File "myfilepath", line 2, in func1
    func2()
  File "myfilepath", line 5, in func2
    func3()
  File "myfilepath", line 8, in func3
    func4()
  File "myfilepath", line 11, in func4
    0/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

However, I actually only get this:

```
File "...Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "myfilepath.py", line 1898, in <lambda>
    widgetMethod(arguments, command = lambda: MyFunction(arguments))
                                                                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "myfilepath", line 2465, in MyFunction
    0/0
    ~^~
```

My problem is that I would like to get the full stack trace, but I am only given the most recent function called.

Comment: It works for me and shows the full error traceback after `tkinter` calls my function. What do you expect the `traceback` to look like? Can you give an example of what you are getting vs what you expect to get? On a side note, if you want to simplify your code a bit, use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_tb).

Comment: It looks right to me. When you use a button command/`.bind`/`.trace`/`.after`, `tkinter` will call your code from inside the `mainloop()`. `tkinter` removes all of traceback that comes from you calling the `.mainloop()`. Right now it looks like you have a button which calls `MyFunction` with `arguments` and inside there you have are trying to divide by 0.

Comment: @TheLizzard That is correct. However, that window is created from another function call which also comes from a preceding function call, and those are not being displayed in the traceback. I know Tkinter does something with threading, is it that Tkinter only traces from the most recent `.mainloop()`, as my example is an error from a `Toplevel()` window?

Comment: `tkinter` does run from another thread. Also you should only have 1 `.mainloop()` in your code (no matter how many `Tk()`/`Toplevel()` widgets you have). Therefore, there's no point in showing the traceback for the `.mainloop()`.